# SSIS Packages don't open up in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I am upgrading my version of Visual Studio from 2019 to 2022. Now that I have installed the newer version of Visual Studio, none of the SSIS projects I had working in 2019 will open in 2022.

I get a message in the solution explorer that says incompatible:

> The application is not installed

I have installed the SQL Server Data Tools package but I do not have the `Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices` toolset installed. I have read that it isn't necessary after VS 2019.

I don't know what else I need to install with and this I'm not quite sure where to turn from here.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: You do need to download and install SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022 extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices

Comment: It is still a **preview**, so expects some bugs and limitations. For example, it supports SSIS run-time 2017, 2019, and 2022 only.